# Firebase pod 'InAppMessagingDisplay'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm having difficulties installing Firebase new feature "In-App Messaging".
When trying to run `pod install` on the project, I get this error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

These are the pod files in my project:

```
target 'MyProject' do
    platform :ios, '10.1'
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'
    pod 'AKPickerView-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift.git', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'Protobuf', '~> 3.2', :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'PromiseKit/CoreLocation', '~> 4.1'
    pod 'GoogleConversionTracking'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'Branch'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Apply'
    pod 'SnapKit', '>= 4.0.0'
    pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 10.0'
    pod 'Bond'
end
```

I've read other questions in here and tried two different solutions.
First I tried this:
1. `pod repo remove master`
2. `pod setup`
3. `pod install`
Which didn't work. Got the same error.

Then I tried this:
1. `pod repo update`
2. `pod deintegrate`
3. `pod install`
With the same result.

Have any of you experienced this and know a solution?

Comment: Just tried it, but got the error again. Even if I try not having any restrictions to the version of those two, I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to update all your Firebase pods (pod update). The minimum firebase version required for me was 5.7.0 and it was 4.0.4
I had the same issue and now it's working very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing your Podfile to make it an [MCVE](/help/mcve), we can reproduce the issue with simply:

```
target 'MyProject' do
    pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'
end
```

So let's look at the specs:

→ https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase
→ https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json
→ Dependency on `"FirebaseInAppMessaging": "0.11.0"`
→ https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseInAppMessaging
→ Redirection to https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/

Which means `Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay` has a dependency on another spec that got REMOVED by Google. To demonstrate the removal:

> $ pod repo update
>   $ pod search FirebaseInAppMessaging
>   [!] Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `FirebaseInAppMessaging`

But this spec exists, it was added nine days ago (Aug 16, 2018, 12:38 AM GMT+8) at: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/a/8/FirebaseInAppMessaging/0.11.0/FirebaseInAppMessaging.podspec.json. So some people may have it in cache.

I suggest you contact Google and ask them when they will restore `FirebaseInAppMessaging`. In the mean time, you can't use it.

Comment: Thank you Cœur! That at least saved me a couple hours :-)
Will try and contact Google then.

Comment: That dependency is occurring due old reference to google analytics pod. Check my answer please

Answer (score 2):

You need higher versions of the following two Firebase SDKs to use in-app messaging

```
pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.0.0'
```

Comment: Right, InAppMessaging was introduced in Firebase 5.6.0

Comment: Which version do you suggest I set them to? Tried setting them both to '~> 5.6', which resulted in this:


"[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/Reachability":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Messaging (~> 5.6) was resolved to 5.6.0, which depends on
      FirebaseMessaging (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
        GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 5.2)

Specs satisfying the 'GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 5.2)' dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 1):

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.7.0'
pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pod install —repo-update`, it could solve your problem.

Comment: Just tried it. Got the same error. Thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: Try to edit your deployment target version with an higher version and retry the command

Comment: Bumped it from 10.1 to 11.0, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue. My podfile was looking like yours. I have been cracking the pods dependencies and I found I was using an old reference for Google Analytics.

I was using `pod 'Google/Analytics'` instead of `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'`.
Once I changed the cocoa pods reference following the list of pods published by Google everything worked fine.

[Pods list published by Google](https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods)